# Is the phrase "I'm not happy unless you are" deliberately ambiguous?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

The phrase "I'm not happy unless you are" is usually understood as "I'm not happy unless you are [happy]". However, it could be understood as "I'm not happy unless you are [not happy]".

Is this phrase ever used with this deliberately ambiguous or double meaning?.

Comment: Possible typo in the second sentence. It should be *'However, it could be **mis**understood as "I'm not happy unless you are [not happy]".'*

Comment: I don't see how it could be understood to mean "I'm not happy unless you are not happy."

Comment: Perhaps another way to ask this questions is: is this a compliment that is actually a veiled insult?

Comment: Not an insult. The speaker is saying that he/she cares about how the other person feels. Nothing hidden.